# How can I see old bounties I have offered?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, questions, bounties, information-display

There is no way that I'm aware of to easily locate questions that you have set bounties on in the past. It seems like there should be, however; perhaps under the "activity" tab.

Comment: What do you mean by 'locate your bounties'?

Comment: If I create a bounty on a question, I'd like the ability to easily locate the question in my profile.  If I asked the question a long time ago based on my activity it might not even appear on the Activity tab as asked.

Comment: You can already see the +100 or whatever in the question listing in your profile. If that is insufficient, please describe what else you have in mind in more detail.

Comment: @Jon, I think he is asking about when he offered a bounty rather than when he won one, though the same procedure applies.

Comment: @Lance: I suspect Nissan is having problems locating all the questions he's started a bounty on. With 65 questions they're not all exaclty in one spot - and on SO the list of questions with a bounyt has become rather large.

Comment: OK, I get it, but I don't know of any simple way to see that, you'll probably just have to use dmckee's method below.

Comment: Having said that, I also suspect better written questions would obviate the need for bounties... but that is a completely off-the-cuff guess based on this one question and not a comprehensive sampling of all Nissan's questions.

Comment: @AnonJr Sometimes your questions are so specific that the potential list of SMEs who could assist are very limited.  You're basically running the risk of never getting face time with them without a bounty to bring your question to prominence.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would use the [bounty tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/135952/cat-man-do?tab=bounties#page_1-bsort_offered) on the users page for that.

[image: bounty tab]

Comment: For the guys who missed it, like me, you have to set it to 'offered' instead of 'active'.

Answer (score 1):

The reputation audit available at `<sitename>/reputation` will list all of your reputation changes. Anything caused by posting a bounty will have the code "8" for BountyStart in the leftmost column. This is a faster method than the reputation graph that is guaranteed to work, but it only gives you the IDs of the posts rather than direct links.

If you want the convenience of links, then I might suggest checking out the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](http://odata.stackexchange.com/) to see if there's a query constructed to look for all posts that a specific user has posted a bounty on.

Answer (score 0):

More complicated that you're asking for but:

You can go to your reputation graph, find the dip in your rep that corresponds to the creation of the bounty, select that part of the graph, and find the questions with the bounty docked in the side bar.

Of course this will start to get harder to do as you rep gets into the 15k range and 100 point moves stop showing up clearly on the graph... Unless you always offer *big* bounties, then you can put the problem back until you have circa 40-50k rep.

Comment: I just did that and it works, but I think for most people who offer bounties ... they are real important things they are trying address and there should be some easy way for the bountied questions to be located.

Answer (score 0):

If you're referring to *active* bounties:

You could go to your "questions" tab and sort by date ("newest"). As bounty questions can't be older than seven days old, you should be able to locate bounty questions quickly because of the blue `+xxx` symbol.

For *inactive* bounties, I think the only way is indeed what dmckee suggests, selecting a period in the graph and scanning for three-digit red `-xxx` entries.

Comment: Not necessarily three digits ... you *can* give a 50 point bounty.

Comment: @Chacha102: You can give a 50 point bounty, but the system's standard 50 point boost makes it 100.